# Change part of url using htaccess removing query parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect a series of urls using part of the urls and deleting the query parameters.

```
ORIGIN: https://mywebsite.com/category/string-1029?query=1

TO: https://mywebsite.com/mycategory/1029
```

As you can see the only thing I want to take advantage of is the numerical code (1029 in the example) of the url (which is the one that changes), to create another path with my own subdirectory and the code itself.

So far I have been able to do this, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)query=1($|&)
RewriteRule ^category/string-(.*)$ /mycategory/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Add `QSD` flag to remove old query string

Comment: "it doesn't seem to work" - In what way? An error? Undesirable redirect? Nothing??